# How to launch android app with emulator and android device

Tags: android-intent, android-emulator

i am facing problem with running on emulator and android device, i have created the emulator and connected with phone as well .

in Manifest file mainActivity if i give

```
   <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

its connecting to the phone and app runs success,  but in emulator not running,

if i change category like below code its launching with emulator and not launching on phone .

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

Could any one tell me what is the best intent-filter i have to give to run both emulator and phone.

Comment: Is your minSDKVersion greater than or equal to the sdk version of your emulator

Answer (score 0):

is like this your menifest content ...

```
<application
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <activity
           android:name=".MainActivity"
           android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
   </application>
```

Comment: Yes same thing in my Menifest file